# Change "Profile" button in Menu to "User.Name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-controls

So I'm trying to Change in the menu the field "Profile" to the User's name.

```
<li><%= link_to "Profile", "#" %></li>
```

So i changed it to

```
<li><%= link_to User.name, "#" %></li>
```

but now in the Menu, it states "User", and not the User's Name.

Any Solution?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you get your currently logged in user via `current_user` method, it should be:

```
<li><%= link_to current_user.name, '#' %></li>
```

What you are doing now is sending `name` message to `User` class instead of `User` instance. Since `User` class doesn't have `name` method defined, you get this error.